# Change switch index with swipes

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, uiswitch

I would like to know is it possible to change switch index with swipes? I am using **gontovnik's** [`DGRunkeeperSwitch`](https://github.com/gontovnik/DGRunkeeperSwitch) library. After implementation it looks like this:

[image]

It uses views for it to work. I am trying to programmatically change it's index after swipe. I tried it like this, it contains my `swipeGesture` code and lines which should change the `index`:

```
let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respond:")
leftSwipe.direction = .Left
view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respond:")
leftSwipe.direction = .Right
view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

func respond(sender: DGRunkeeperSwitch!, gesture: UIGestureRecognizer){
        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer{
            switch swipeGesture.direction{
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
                sender.selectedIndex == 0

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
                sender.selectedIndex == 1


            default:
                break

            }
        }

}
```

But it gives me the **signal SGABRT** error

> 'unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd788536ad0'

I also tried to swipe change the value on default `UISwitch` which worked like this:

```
mySwitch.on == true
```

What I am doing wrong, can you guys give me the right direction? I think I am forcing something but I do not know what.

Comment: which line does it throw the error on

Comment: Don't know because it directs me to appDelegate.

Comment: add a exception breakpoint to your code

Comment: @Shubhank Whete exactly I should put it? After the swipe?

Answer (score 0):

`respond:` is not the correct signature for a function with 2 parameters.

You should use `#selector(...)` to define the action, probably something like `#selector(YourClass.respond(_:gesture:))`

Comment: It leads me to the exc_bad_access error. Does it mean that it is trying to send a message to a block of memory that can't execute that message or maybe an object is not initialized?